# Index/Match VBA alternative to search inside a table and its columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need to search inside a table and its columns (search a value inside column A and return a value from column B) and I dislike using the Index/Match combination because I'm preparing the workbook for a novice user and he is not able to grasp the Index/Match logic.

Comment: Why not use VLOOKUP ?  That's simpler than index/match

Comment: Also, if the user isn't capable of learning `Index/Match` (or `VLOOKUP()`), I'm not sure if a UDF/Macro is a good idea. Sure, it may be "simpler", but then they'll have to enable macros all the time which may not be a good habit for such a novice to get in to.  Plus, it's *incredibly useful* to learn `Index/Match`/`VLOOKUP()` for a multitude of reasons, so perhaps consider using it, and just educating the user?

Comment: Give a user a UDF instead of teaching them INDEX/MATCH. Hmmm... sounds like giving a handgun to someone who cannot light a match.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP, but how to write a simple formula to return a summed value if  there are more than one values corresponding in the searched column? Despite INDEX/MATCH is standard and a UDF is... an UDF, "SearchValInCol2" is undoubtedly more concise and readable.

Comment: For that you would use sumifs()

Comment: sumifs() will return zero if the column to read contains strings; the UDF instead will return the first value for strings or the summed value for numbers.

Comment: re: '*the UDF instead will ...*' What UDF? I see no UDF code or any code for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any simple/elegant formula to do this (other than the Index/Match combination), then I wrote the following VBA code.

As a bonus, the function automatically sum values from the column to read if there are more than one corresponding rows matching.

```
' return a value taken from a column searching for a value in another column;
' the function works in the same way as Index(Match());
' if the column ColNameToRead contains number values, and if ValueToSearch is found more then one time in the column ColNameToSearch, then the returned value
' is the sum of all occurrence found.
Public Function SearchValInCol(TabName As String, ColNameToSearch As String, ValueToSearch As Variant, ColNameToRead As String)

    Application.Volatile (True)   ' see "Excel Recalculation"  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx

    SearchValInCol = "Error, value not found!"

    ' search table in all Worksheets; exit if not found
    Dim foundTable
    Dim objSheet
    Dim objTable
    foundTable = 0
    For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each objTable In objSheet.ListObjects
            If objTable.Name = Trim(TabName) Then
                Set foundTable = objTable
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If IsNumeric(foundTable) Then Exit Function  ' exit function if the table is not found


    ' search column named ColNameToSearch in table; exit if not found
    Dim foundColumnToSearch
    Dim counter
    foundColumnToSearch = 0
    For counter = 1 To foundTable.ListColumns.Count
        If foundTable.HeaderRowRange(counter) = Trim(ColNameToSearch) Then
            Set foundColumnToSearch = foundTable.ListColumns(counter).DataBodyRange
            Exit For
        End If
    Next counter
    If IsNumeric(foundColumnToSearch) Then Exit Function ' exit function if the column is not found


    ' search column named ColNameToRead in table; exit if not found
    Dim foundColumnToRead
    foundColumnToRead = 0
    For counter = 1 To foundTable.ListColumns.Count
        If foundTable.HeaderRowRange(counter) = Trim(ColNameToRead) Then
            Set foundColumnToRead = foundTable.ListColumns(counter).DataBodyRange
            Exit For
        End If
    Next counter
    If IsNumeric(foundColumnToRead) Then Exit Function ' exit function if the column is not found


    ' search value ValueToSearch in column foundColumnToSearch; exit if not found
    Dim cellVal
    Dim retVal
    retVal = 0
    For counter = 1 To foundColumnToSearch.Rows.Count
        If foundColumnToSearch.Cells(counter, 1) = ValueToSearch Then
            ' if the value to search is a number, sum it with the previous value; otherwise return the first occurrence
            If IsNumeric(foundColumnToRead.Cells(counter, 1)) Then
                retVal = retVal + foundColumnToRead.Cells(counter, 1)
            Else
                retVal = foundColumnToRead.Cells(counter, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next counter

    SearchValInCol = retVal

End Function
```

To search inside in the following table (Table1) the "article" "vino" returning a value from the column "quantity"

```
article     quantity
vino               7
acqua              8
patate             5
vino               7
```

can be used the following formula:

```
=SearchVal("Table1"; Table1[[#Headers];[article]]; "vino"; Table1[[#Headers];[quantity]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, simpler solution, always with VBA, is the following

```
' return a value taken from a column searching for a value in another column;
' the function works in the same way as Index(Match());
' if the column ColToRead contains number values, and if ValueToSearch is found more then one time in the column ColToSearch, then the returned value
' is the sum of all occurrence found.
Public Function SearchValInCol2(ColToSearch, ValueToSearch As Variant, ColToRead)

    Application.Volatile (True)   ' see "Excel Recalculation"  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx

    SearchValInCol2 = "Error, value not found!"

    ' search value ValueToSearch in column ColToSearch; exit if not found
    Dim counter
    Dim cellVal
    Dim retVal
    retVal = 0
    For counter = 1 To ColToSearch.Rows.Count
        If ColToSearch.Cells(counter, 1) = ValueToSearch Then
            ' if the value to search is a number, sum it with the previous value; otherwise return the first occurrence
            If IsNumeric(ColToRead.Cells(counter, 1)) Then
                retVal = retVal + ColToRead.Cells(counter, 1)
            Else
                retVal = ColToRead.Cells(counter, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next counter

    SearchValInCol2 = retVal

End Function
```

To search in the following table "Table1"

```
article     quantity
vino               7
acqua              8
patate             5
vino               7
```

a formula calling the function can be :

```
=SearchValInCol2(Table1[article];"vino";Table1[quantity])
```

that is more concise and readable of the previous solution, and avoid using inside the formula the literal string "Table1" that won't be updated if the table name will change.